# How to run multple lines of python code from shell, instead of from a script

Tags: python, command-line

I want to run python code from the shell instead of from a script.

I searched everywhere and found suggestions about using `echo` or `Shift+Enter` and using `^` at the end of the line, but `^` and `shift+Enter` didn't work in python shell, and I need to if there is a way to separate commands in the shell.

For example I need to run this from python shell instead of from a script:

```
If x > y
   print ("x is greater than y.")
```

but non of the options I tried worked.

Comment: Do you mean [the REPL](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/repl/) or your system shell?

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear as you already received one downvote, so it should be ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:` to issue a line separator.

i.e.

```
if x > y:
   print ("x is greater than y.")
```

Comment: oh! I am ashamed a lot for this childish mistake!!!! I code in pyCharm and I need to use command line, I was struggling for 2 hours! just for missing : ! Thanks man! again sorry for this low level question!

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to enter Python code in your shell, then try something like

```
python -c 'if x > y:
    print(("x is greater than y")'
```

assuming you are using a Bourne-compatible shell (Linux etc). This has the major drawback that your Python code cannot easily contain a single quote (though if you know the quoting rules of the shell it's of course not impossible or even unobvious how to create an expression which evaluates to a single quote).

However, the common way to do this (and perhaps the only way on Windows?) is to type the Python code into a file and then run it with

```
python filename.py
```

where `filename.py` is the name of the file where you saved your Python code.

You can of course run simply

```
python
```

to enter the Python interpreter in interactive mode, where you can type in Python expressions and have them evaluated immediately. When you type an expression which ends with a colon, Python changes the prompt from `>>>` to `...` to indicate that it expects one or more indented lines. (Type just a newline immediately at the `...` prompt to exit this mode.)